# Prove that Z(integers) and A = {a ∈ Z| a = 4r + 2 for some r ∈Z} have the same cardinality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble coming up with a proof.

I know that to how an equal cardinality I must show each of the sets has the same numbers of elements (in this case infinite integers). I have begun my proof as follows:

$\{a \in Z| a = 4r + 2\}$ for some $r \in Z$

Because $a$ is an integer than $a$ means that some integer is equal to $4r+2$.

Because an integer can be positive or negative, we must show that $a$ is either $2k$ or $2k+1$

> Case 1: Show $a$ is even

$a = 4r+2$

$a = 4(2k)+2$

$a = 8k+2$

$a = 2(4k+1)$

$a = 2(n)$

> Case 2: show that $a$ is odd

$a = 4r+2$

$a = 4(2k+1)+2$

$a = 8k+6$

$a = 2(4k+2)+1$

$a = 2(n)+1$

Because we have proven $a$ is an even or odd integer then some $a$ can be represented by some even or odd integer. Thus for whatever $a$, there is an integer $r$ that can represent it and thus they have the same cardinality.

Is my proof proof correct and if not could you explain the correct process I should be taking?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean when you say that "some $a$ can be represented by some even or odd integer". If you want to show that two sets have the same cardinality, the best way is usually to define an explicit function between them and show it is a bijection. In this case, $f(r) = 4r+2$ seems like a good candidate...

Comment: I'm not sure If I follow. What would be the next step to solve for cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

We say that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection between them, that is, a function $f : A \to B$ such that:

1. (Injective) Whenever $f(x) = f(y)$ for $x,y$ in $A$ we have $x=y$, and
2. (Surjective) For any $y$ in $B$ there is an $x$ in $A$ with $f(x)=y$.

So in this case we'll take $B$ to be $\mathbb{Z}$ (the integers), and $A$ the set $\{a \in \mathbb{Z} : a=4r+2 \text{ for some } r \in \mathbb{Z}  \}$.

Let's consider the function $f(x) = 4x+2$.

Firstly, if $r$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $f(r) = 4r+2$ for an integer $r$, so $f(r) \in A$. This tells us that $f$ is indeed a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $A$. Now we want to show that it is a bijection.

1. Suppose we have $f(x) = f(y)$ for integers $x$ and $y$. This means that $4x+2 = 4y+2$. Can you see how this implies that $x=y$?
2. Let's pick any element $a$ in $A$. By the definition of $A$ we know that there is some integer $r$ with $a=4r+2$. So $f(r)=a$.

And now we've shown that $f$ is a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $A$, therefore the two sets have the same cardinality.